# How should I reference an answer in other question that solved my question with a different approach?

Tags: support

I have a newly created [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259236/replace-android-default-font-file/36259446), I'm still searching for answers, then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application/16883281#16883281) which doesn't answer my question but it solve the issue I'm trying to acheive. Anyways that answer was not yet accepted by OP [*last login at 2014*].

My question is about *replacing a font file*, not *replacing an object on runtime* which that answer gave. It gave a different approach but solved my problem.

Now I want to reference that answer for future people who will run into same problem as mine, because though it's a different question, it gives solution by a different approach.

**How should I reference that answer in my question?**

I see some options:

- I will answer my question with link to that answer. (I see questions that did that.)
- I will just comment the link and tell that my question was not solved but it solved my problem.

Comment: I would self answer my own question and give reference to the other answer by explaning and linking to it and of course upvote the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that answer helped you *but* it did not entirely solve your issue, you can self-answer your own question with the code that actually worked. Self-answering is [explicitly allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

You can always add a line "based on ..." somewhere.

Comment: What if the other answer *does* entirely solve my issue, even though the question was different?